# Different contents in the same URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I have a blog powered by Wordpress. I need to show different contents in a same webpage according to the date.

Say I have few posts with the url format: `domain.com/post-010215, domain.com/post-020215,` etc.
If today is `01022015` it has to show the first post in the URL `domain.com/daily-content/` and likewise for the different days.

Now I'm using a JavaScript to redirect the posts to particular days post.

The snippet I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yy = today.getFullYear() - 2000; //1900 is 0!
    if(dd<10){
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if(mm<10){
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    today = dd.toString() + mm.toString() + yy;
    toURL = "domain.com/" + today + "/";

    window.location= toURL;
</script>
```

How can I acquire this in Php using any thing?
I read somewhere that it can be acquired by using the php database query. But there is no guide to do it.

Here is the example of what I want:
http://www.catholic.org/bible/daily_reading/

Comment: acquire what in PHP? the data to display in a template? or something else? potentially there are a lot of topics youre covering in your question.. we need a place to start.

Comment: I just need a script that grabs the post content in the database that has the URL with date like I had asked in my question. Check that example link. I need to acquire like that. Thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

It would be a very verbose answer to write all of the code you might need, since it depends on how you want to approach the problem, but if the post information is stored in a database, or perhaps a file, you need only get the Date in PHP when someone visits the page, get the content from either a file or query with that Date, and present it to the screen. Redirecting the user is actually quite unnecessary.

In a framework like CodeIgniter, or a template engine like Smarty, this would be relatively easy to achieve, assuming there is some naming convention used, or there is a database of post information.

To give a more specific answer would require more specific information about the layout of your site, and at that point, we'd essentially be designing your page for you.

Comment: I just need a script that grabs the post content in the database that has the URL with date like I had asked in my question. Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: That is different from the example you showed. You didn't even say that you had a database of posts, only that you heard somewhere that you could use it.

Comment: I had mentioned that my site is powered by Wordpress. Wordpress write the posts in the database only. I meant this only.

Comment: What I meant by that was, the way you are doing it in Javascript completely avoids the database altogether.

Comment: Yes, I used that Javascript in a static HTML page. It will just fetch the Date and redirect the user to the current day's Post. But I want it to be dynamic like what you see in the example. Thanks.

Comment: Then, like I mentioned in the answer, I think an easy solution would be to use a template engine like Smarty. Or, when someone visits the page, get the current date, look it up in the database, and display the post.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Can I acquire this with that template. Will it fetch the current date and show that post for the user. 
Thank you for the quick response and the selfless help.

Comment: No, it can't do that for you. No matter what option you choose, you will have to get the information from the database in one form or another. Just get the Date, look it up, then display the information. It should be a very basic SQL query.